# Randomly load different JavaScript between each page load using loadExternalHTMLPage

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a site and I want it to randomly load a different HTML5 Javascript animation each time the page is loaded, JavaScript is by far one of the weakest of my skills and I appreciate any help in advance and if this happens to be duplicate (I've tried searching) then please vote for the question to be closed.

Basically the method I have used is a dirty one and most likely the reason its not working, basically I tried randommath and had no luck and put this down to my JS skills being extremely weak, the alternative method which looked easier doesn't work either and this is basically inserting a HTML on page load, so for example a.html and b.html which both contain different scripts.

This is what my code looks like:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/insert.js"></script><!-- This inserts the Random Page -->
</head>
<body onload="loadExternalHTMLPage()"> 
    <div id="injectjs"> </div>
    <canvas="id"> </canvas>
<script src="js/animation-lib-pageA.js"></script><!--Library for pageA --> 
<script src="js/animation-lib-pageB.js"></script><!--Library for pageB -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Inject.js**

```
function loadExternalHTMLPage() {

var xmlhttp;
var pagesToDisplay = ['a.html', 'b.html'];
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

} else {

xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

document.getElementById("jsinsert").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;

}

}
var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * pagesToDisplay.length);
xmlhttp.open("GET", pagesToDisplay[randomnumber], true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Most JS Guru's should be able to see that I'm randomly inserting a.html and b.html on page load, now this works but the problem is the scripts contained within a.html and b.html are not executing. (using firebug I can clearly see that the scripts are being inserted as intended).

so for example a and b looks like:

**a.html**

```
<script> window.onload = function () { }</script>
```

**b.html**

```
<script> window.onload = function () { } </script>
```

Basically the code within A and B are valid and work fine within this insert and I've filled the above examples as just a placeholder. A and B both contain JavaScript that executes animation contained within the canvas but it doesn't work at present and I suspect its something to do with the fact I'm loading the scripts after the page has been loaded. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can randomly load the html for A or B and then run its animation.**

This example uses jQuery which makes the task of loading remote html easier.  Here is a link to the jquery .load function which replaces an existing elements html with the downloaded html: http://api.jquery.com/load/  If you want pure javascript, you can use that [messier!] alternative, but the logic remains the same.

These are the steps:

1. Be sure the web page has loaded,
2. Randomly pick A or B to load/execute,
3. Replace the html in #injectjs with htmlForA or htmlForB,
4. Wait until the html has been fully replaced,
5. Run the appropriate animationA or animationB.

Here is starter code.  (Be sure you include the jQuery library)

```
<script>

window.onload(){

    // randomly load html+animation A or B

    if(Math.random()<.50){

        $('#injectjs').load(
              'yourSite.com/HtmlForA.html',   // first load the html for A
              function(){ animationA(); }     // then run animationA
        );

    }else{

        $('#injectjs').load(
              'yourSite.com/HtmlForB.html',   // first load the html for B
              function(){ animationB(); }     // then run animationB
        );

    }

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `eval()` to execute the content you downloaded ... :) (not recommended).

Or you can modify the html page on server to include the random script you want before serving the page to the user (you don't state platform) since it's anyways changed at page load.